# TFS build, which file do I add my custom tasks to?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm new to TFS build.

I am looking at the .proj file right now, and I see it references the microsoft.teamfoundation.build.targets file.

Which file do I add my custom tasks to?  And where is that file located (if it's not the .proj file)?

I want to add a custom task to run dotfuscator (command line tool) and pass it an .xml file as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the custom steps into the main proj file or you can create your own targets file if you want to keep the two separate.
You should leave the microsoft.teamfoundation.build.targets alone!

Answer (score 1):

The add custom targets to the main TFSBuild.proj file.  Microsoft include a number of target names designed for you to override them by creating a target with that name in your TFSBuild.proj file.

For example, I have a target that runs and creates my Wix installer, zips documentation up etc and that lives in the

Target which occurs towards the end of the Team Build process, just before everything is copied over to the drop location.

For a reference to all the targets that you can override in a TFS2008 build see the following article in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604.aspx

Good luck,

Martin.